# Application cannot make Get Requests

Tags: java, teamcity

```
IOException Error in getContentFromUrl method: java.io.FileNotFoundEx
```

We are trying to hit a URL: http://somewebsite.com/somefolder/dosomething?zip=75070&servCat=1

It used to generate an XML file on the fly and get us. All of a sudden it started giving us that error. When we access the URL from any computer and even on the actual server, we can see the XML file. Just not on the application itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that the somewebsite.com does not point to itself? try doing an nslookup and verify that it is getting the correct IP.